# How to replace axis argument in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the code as below

```py
np.array([points[label==k].mean(axis = 0) for k in range(self.k)])
```

Points is a n x d array, label is a 1 x n array, with values up to k and k is a number.

My goal is to remove the axis argument and still get the same same result and also the indexing with array part label == k, I would like to rewrite.

Does any of you have a method of doing so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are after a vectorized solution. Here's one with `matrix-multiplication` -

```
def matmul(points, label):
    k = label.max()+1
    mask = label == np.arange(k)[:,None]
    out = mask.dot(points)/mask.sum(1,keepdims=True)
    return out
```

Here's another with `np.add.reduceat` -

```
def add_reduceat(points, label):
    k = label.max()+1
    sidx = label.argsort()
    ps = points[sidx]
    ls = label[sidx]

    cutidx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,ls[:-1] != ls[1:],True])
    lens = np.diff(cutidx)
    out = np.full((k,points.shape[1]),np.nan)

    idx_rows = ls[cutidx[:-1]]
    mean_vals = np.add.reduceat(ps,cutidx[:-1],axis=0)/lens[:,None]
    out[idx_rows] = mean_vals
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [220]: n,d,k = 10000,100,100
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: points = np.random.rand(n,d)
     ...: label = np.random.randint(0,k,(n))

In [221]: out0 = np.array([points[label==k_i].mean(axis = 0) for k_i in range(k)])

In [222]: np.allclose(matmul(points, label),out0)
Out[222]: True

In [223]: np.allclose(add_reduceat(points, label),out0)
Out[223]: True
```

Comment: These are some good solutions, I like the mask option alot! It works perfectly in numpy. 
The fork of numpy i am have not implemented keepdims, is there a way to do it without that?

Comment: @Shadesfear Yes, just use `mask.sum(1)[:,None]` to replace `mask.sum(1,keepdims=True)`.

Comment: thanks! That is perfect, do you have any material i can read on how to write my own vectorized code?

Comment: @Shadesfear well vectorization is a very broad topic. I would just suggest following the vectorization tagged questions on here. Can't suggest any external reference at the moment.